# Trouble with UpdatePanel in an ASP.NET WebForms solution

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

So I have a mixed situation here and I thought I was on the right track but it doesn't seem to be working out.

So here is what I want.....

I have a webpage that uses a map to plot a point. I do not want to interfere with what the user is doing, but I want to periodically check the database to see if there is a need to update the points. No need = just start the timer over. Have Update = Auto Trigger the click event of a "refresh" button the user can manually click on.

Here is the road I was\am trying ....

So I have the UI working like I want. I have an update panel that contains a javascript countdown timer. When the timer is up, it triggers the "Click" event of a hidden button. The code-behind checks the database.

If their is no update in the database, there is nothing to do so the callback returns to the update panel and the timer starts over.

Here is what is not working....

If there IS an update, my code behind then calls the needed routine that redoes everything on the page (e.g. rebuilds the map and such). The problem is that even though the code actually runs, the page doesn't reload.

I'm assuming it is because the whole UpdatePanel workflow is designed to ignore any page updates that effect objects NOT inside the Update Panel.

I would post code, but there really isn't any. Basically on my form I have my page with a bunch of stuff. On that page there is an UpdatePanel that contains a JavaScript and a label (to display the timer countdown for the user).

In the Code_Behind for my hidden button (that is called by the JavaScript), there is simple code like.....

```
if (PageNeedsToBeUpdated() == true) 
{
      BuildPage();
}
```

So when the statement is FALSE...everything works. But when it is True, I need the entire Page to actually reload.

Thanks....and if I'm totally going about this the wrong way, I'm totally willing to go a different direction.

Comment: How about adding autopostback =true  on the backend code which will refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer control under the UpdatePanel Control and Set Interval property of Timer to specific time interval. Then Put your logic in Timer_Tick Event. Now at particular time interval your UpdatePanel will be Updated.

Comment: So you're saying put a timer inside my update panel that I enable when I need the full page to refresh?

Comment: If you want to refresh your entire page then you can do in HTML also. For example If you want to refresh your page every 10 seconds then add a <meta> tag in the <head> section of the html like this : <meta http-equiv=”refresh” content=”10;” /> and if you want to implement this functionality from Code behind then you can do like this : Response.AppendHeader(“Refresh”, “10”);

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I definitely have access to the response inside my code the question will be is if the append header is ignored because it's not inside the update panel

Comment: Use <meta> tag in <head> section it will refresh the page.

Comment: Tried the Timer... doesn't work. The Timer Fires, the tick even changes contents of the page outside the update panel, but it gets ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible but maybe you guys can tell me. Would it be possible to have my code return some value to the JavaScript so that the script knows whether to restart the timer or trigger a full post back?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions...I have it sorted out. I've shut down for the day so no code to post for now. Basically I ended up using a single script on the outside if the update panel and a label with a hidden button inside the panel.

The button click event changes the text of the label and the javascript reads that value to determine what action to take including triggering a different button that is also outside the update panel.